# In Lambda is it possible to get the result of a callback before the process finishes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, callback, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm currently implementing a webservice with lambda and api gateway.
I don't want to delay the response of the service because it is just a redirection, but in the background I'm doing some actions.
Is it possible to return something to the client before the action is finsished ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Node.js, but the Lambda/API Gateway model is not really designed for this.

What you can do (we do this in our live environments as well) is the following:

Lambda function A is reachable via API Gateway. Lambda A receives a request, saves a "job definition" file in an S3 bucket and sends a response to the user that the request has been received.

Lambda function B is not reachable via the API Gateway, but has the "object created" S3 event trigger. This lambda function is triggered because Lambda A created an object in the bucket and parses the background job.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
I'm currently using Node.js, do you have a better solution with this platform ?
Implementing 2 lambdas is too much to maintain over time for this kind of procedure.

Comment: You can just invoke the Lambda B directly from Lambda A, so long as you set the invocationType to "event" when invoking Lambda B. No need to involve S3 at all.

Comment: Great thank you, I was hoping I could process stuff after the return...

Comment: You can also call a Lambda function with the 'event' invocationType directly from API Gateway, but in that case you don't get much control over the sync response back to the client.

Comment: @idbehold you're right. Just call the other lambda using the Node SDK from within the other function and don't wait for the callback but just continue. This is much easier!